Do I need a transit visa changing planes in Oslo, separate tickets?
Do I need a transit visa to change planes in  Oslo from USA to Istanbul with a four-hour layover and no checked baggage?

What is your nationality?  I would not need a visa but you might.

The first airline will consider that your final destination is Oslo and will thus require you to have documentation proving that you can enter the Schengen Area. So if you usually need a visa to enter Schengen you will need one here (a full visa, not airport transit).
